# Trial windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

How to close a windows form application as trial after 10 times used?
This form don't need anything as login or registration.
Just when I run the program and close it, after 10 times used, a MessageBox 
appear to say The form is Trial.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What options did you consider? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Just run my application, after 10 times using the application just hint that this application is trial, thats all

Comment: And how did you achieve that? Code is better than vague descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample you can use. Add application settings called LoadCount and set scope to user. Now here is code how to handle load count:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check load count...
        int loadCount = ApplicationSettingsDemo.Properties.Settings.Default.LoadCount;
        if (loadCount > 10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Trial version expired!");
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
              ApplicationSettingsDemo.Properties.Settings.Default.LoadCount += 1;
              ApplicationSettingsDemo.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
                "Failed to save settings", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Take notice this settings are not protected by default.

Comment: In Bind Properties which field must called LoadCount ??

Comment: Inside your solution explorer open project properties. Go to tab "Settings" and add new property named "LoadCount". Set type to "int" and scope to "User". Set default value to "0".

Comment: You are welcome. You can vote this answer as useful if you are satisfied with it.